# Minimising a function after Arnoldi decomposition

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I'm can't seem to figure out what this question is asking me:

Let

$$
       A= \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 2 & 0 &0 \\
        -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
0 &0 & 2 &1\\
        \end{bmatrix} 
 r^0= \begin{bmatrix}
        2\\
        1\\
        -1\\
0\\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

Find  the vector *y* that minimises $\lVert r^0-AV^1y\rVert_2$.

I've found both the Arnoldi decomposition in the form $AV^1=V^2H$, and the QR decomposition which are as follows:

$AV^1=V^2H$:
$$
       A \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{\sqrt 6}{3}\\
        \frac{\sqrt 6}{6}\\
        -\frac{\sqrt 6}{6}\\
0\\
        \end{bmatrix} 
 = \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{\sqrt 6}{3} & \frac{2\sqrt 39}{39}\\
        \frac{\sqrt 6}{6} & -\frac{5\sqrt 39}{39}\\
        -\frac{\sqrt 6}{6} & -\frac{\sqrt 39}{39}\\
0 & -\frac{\sqrt 39}{13}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{2}{3}\\
\frac{\sqrt 26}{3}\end{bmatrix} $$
$QR$ decomposition :

$H=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt 30}{15}\\
\frac{\sqrt 195}{15}\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt 30}{3}\end{bmatrix}$

So I know what $r^0$, $A$, $V^1$ are, but what does y equal, and how do I minimise $\lVert r^0-AV^1y\rVert_2$ ?